# React Navigation v.5 Tab Bar Icon Navigate to Modal

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-bottom-tab

Anyone know a good alternative to tabBarOnPress in **react navigation v.5**? I want to navigate to a modal stack when a user presses a tabIcon, (i.e. cancel its default navigation behavior) but the icon seems to navigate to the Tab Screen first, then navigates to the modal.

For clarification, here is my PostIcon TabIcon Component

```js
export const PostStackIcon: React.FC<TabBarIconProps> = ({ size, color }) => {
    const navigation = useNavigation();

    const goToCreatePost = () => {
        navigation.navigate('CreatePostStack', { screen: 'CreatePost'});
    }

    return (
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => goToCreatePost()}>
            <Icon
                name="Post"
                width={size * 2}
                height={size}
                fillOpacity={0}
                stroke={color} 
                secondaryStroke={color}
            />
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Official document](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events/#listeners-prop-on-screen)

You can use `listeners` prop  of `Tab.Screen`, this is the closest alternative to `tabBarOnPress` IMHO.

Below is quoted from the documents:

> Sometimes you might want to add a listener from the component where you defined the navigator rather than inside the screen. You can use the `listeners` prop on the `Screen` component to add listeners. The `listeners` prop takes an object with the event names as keys and the listener callbacks as values.

Example:

```js
<Tabs.Screen
  name="Chat"
  component={Chat}
  listeners={{
    tabPress: e => {
      // Prevent default action
      e.preventDefault();
    },
  }}
/>
```

> You can also pass a callback which returns the object with listeners. It'll receive `navigation` and `route` as the arguments.

Example:

```js
<Tabs.Screen
  name="Chat"
  component={Chat}
  listeners={({ navigation, route }) => ({
    tabPress: e => {
      // Prevent default action
      e.preventDefault();

      // Do something with the `navigation` object
      navigation.navigate('AnotherPlace');
    },
  })}
/>
```